# Azure Data Factory Disable Triggers On Release

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

I've been trying to get Data Factory Deployments working through VSTS and am mostly there, but I'm getting a failure due to the triggers needing to be disabled to be overwritten. Error message below:

```
Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger : HTTP Status Code: BadRequest
Error Code: TriggerEnabledCannotUpdate
Error Message: Cannot update enabled Trigger; it needs to be disabled first.
Request Id: <id number here>
Timestamp (Utc):06/17/2018 21:31:49
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" -Data ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger], ErrorResponseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.RemoveAzureDataFactoryTriggerCommand
```

I get this error when both trying to do a straight deployment, but also when manually running a powershell script to remove the trigger

```
Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroupName" -DataFactoryName "DataFactoryName" -Name "TriggerName"
```

I cant find a way to disable a trigger via powershell or during a release. Can anyone help me find a way around this? Without it I cant do Continuous integration releases with the Data Factory.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call Stop-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger before removing it.

Iterate round all defined triggers and set to variable

```
$triggersADF = Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName <DataFactoryName> -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName>
```

Disable all triggers

```
$triggersADF | ForEach-Object { Stop-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -DataFactoryName <DataFactoryName> -Name $_.name -Force }
```

re-enable triggers post deployment

```
$triggersADF | ForEach-Object { Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -DataFactoryName <DataFactoryName> -Name $_.name -Force }
```

Comment: I have just found a script at the bottom of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment) page which does this for you and also iterates round the list of triggers. Note someone has flagged an issue with the code currently that is doesn't quite work but offers an alternative.

Comment: You could get just the triggers that are not Stopped, applying a filter in the first command,  like that: 
   | Where-Object { $_.RuntimeState -ne "Stopped"}